# Hand gestures recognition problom

Tags: python, opencv

I have project to Hand gestures recognition system ,this system works in real time and the gestures be dynamic and static ,and must create database for gestures.
I need the help in my project please
I use python and opencv
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Thanhs,I want to create database of gestures and how generation the command that associated with gesture and to now donot know how make dynamic gesture.

Comment: That is not a question and the topic is too broad for SO. On this site you can ask *specific* programming questions.